# Compute the distance between two points with standard normal distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose the position of points $x_1$, $x_2$, $x_3,\ldots, x_{10}$ on real line satisfies standard normal distribution. Then for a new point $x$, set $d_i(x):=|x-x_i|$, $i=1,\ldots, 10$. Compute the density function $$p(x):=\min_{i}\{d_i(x)\}$$

I, apparently, get confused on how to write done $d_i$ and how to have $min$ function. Please advise!

Comment: Can you do it with just one random variable?

Comment: @Ian This is where I got stuck. Do I have, let's say, $d_1$ is just the integration from $x$ to $x_1$ by using density function of standard normal?

Comment: Not quite: first $x-x_1 $ is normal with mean $x $ and variance 1. So you first need to be able to compute $E|X|$ for such a r.v. So this is an integral up to $x $ with one sign and past $x $ with the other sign.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will re-phrase a little. We have $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ independent random variables, with distribution $N(0,1)$, and we want to compute the PDF of 
$$ Y(x) = \min_{i\in [1,n]}\left| x-X_i\right|.$$
Obviously $Y$ is a non-negative random variable. For any $t>0$, the probability that $Y$ exceeds $t$ equals the probability that *any* $X_i$ lie outside $[x-t,x+t]$, hence:
$$ \mathbb{P}[Y(x)\geq t] = \left(1-\int_{x-t}^{x+t}\phi(u)\,du\right)^n $$
where $\phi$ is the PDF of the standard normal variable. The previous line gives the CDF of $Y(x)$, hence we may recover the PDF of $Y(x)$ by differentiating the previous line with respect to $t$, by exploiting the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$ f_Y(t) = n\cdot\left(\phi(x+t)-\phi(x-t)\right)\cdot\left(\int_{x-t}^{x+t}\phi(u)\,du\right)^{n-1}\cdot\mathbb{1}_{t\geq 0}.$$